# PDFlib - editing a page that's been ended/closed

Tags: pdflib

How can I revisit a page in PDFlib that's been closed using `$p->end_page_ext("");` at a later stage to continue adding elements to it?

I other words, once a page is terminated by `$p->end_page_ext("");`, is it possible to recall it to add more elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this with `$p->suspend_page()/$p->resume_page()`.

You find a sample in the [PDFlib cookbook](https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pagination/page_x_of_y/php/).

```php
$p->show_xy("Page 2", $x, $y);

/* Suspend page 2 to resume it later */
$p->suspend_page("");
...
/* Revisit page 2 */
$p->resume_page("pagenumber 2");
```

(see PDFlib 9.2 API reference, chapter 3.3 "*Page Functions*" for details.)